# Human readable way to represent PGP keys (Decentralized client authentication)

Tags: authentication, encryption, pgp

I'm working on a distributed application, and we need a way to authorize clients. Every client has a PGP keypair associated with them, and we require them to enter their private key (which is not stored) through which their pubkey is derived and used to identify clients and modify their fields on the distributed database.

Now, considering user experience, entering a private key on a website whenever you need to do something is troublesome. But we also cannot maintain a central database for username/password based authentication as that creates a single failure point (not what the distributed application is meant to do)

I am hoping there is some way to get an easier to remember human readable descriptor of the private key which can be used to authenticate if something like that exists. Any other ideas are appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw a bunch of ideas to clarify the question:

**Are you certain that PGP is suited for your needs?**

I feel like you should provide some more details to be sure:
- How are the private and public keys used exactly? I understand the following : user inputs its private key, information is decrypted and modified, public key is deduced from private and used to encrypt the updated information.
- How is this different from using a regular password and being able to authenticate the user and encrypt data?
- You seems to send private keys on the network, and they should remain private.

**How you could use a regular password:**
User has a password, your application uses a function (e.g sha256, [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function),...) to make it usable by classical encryption algorithms (e.g AES). With the same (not stored) key, you can then encrypt and decrypt datas. You just have to make sure that decryption is valid, by adding a known value at the beginning of the data (e.g a part of the key).

Quick example:

```
password: "WeakPassword"
key: sha256("WeakPassword"+"MySalt") = 493e3ae...b2eec8ef
Decrypt(data,key)
clearData = "493e3ae{123;456}" //valid, because you can check the beginning
Encrypt(clearData,key)
```

Advantages: usable passwords, faster symmetric encryption

**Use a QR code**
If you stick to PGP and have a camera available it is pretty handy.
You could also use hexadecimal, base64, ... but for a 2048 bits RSA key, that still gets you hundreds of characters.